# Hot and cold water mix

Tags: bathroom, shower

My hot and cold water mix in the shower lasts only about 2 minutes ,then the water goes cold ,would like to know the reason ,its only happening in my shower .

Comment: if its just the shower, you may have a faulty thermostatic mixing valve.  otherwise, more info is required

Answer (score 1):

There's an adjustable & replaceable valve behind your shower's handle(s). This likely needs to be replaced, since it won't just pop out of adjustment due to it not being mechanical, as in a broken spring or such. The quickest resolution is to call a Plumber to get everything back to proper operation tonight or tomorrow.